# Is it possible to implement ArangoDB sharding by database (rather than collection or shardKey)?

Tags: database, arangodb, sharding

I have a large Arango instance with lots of databases - one for each project. Each projects database has a bunch of collections and a lot of data. The databases look something like

```
project1
project2
project3
...
project500
```

I'd like to distribute query load by sharding the instance so that each project database runs on a separate server, or spin up multiple large hosts and have Arango set things up automatically. However it seems like ArangoDB sharding only works at the collection level (for instance by record _key within a collection).

Is there any way to setup sharding by database? If not, are there any best practices for running/orchestrating multiple Arango instances?

Answer (score 6):

one of options to run multiple instances is to use Docker Swarm.
with example below you can run multiple instances of ArangoDB

you'll need

- [Docker](https://docs.docker.com/install/)
- with initialized Swarm [docker swarm init [OPTIONS]](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/swarm_init/)
- optionaly with more nodes added via [docker swarm join [OPTIONS] HOST:PORT](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/swarm_join/#description)
- and set group labels on nodes via [docker node update --label-add group=group1 [node-name]](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/manage-nodes/#add-or-remove-label-metadata), `group1` on first node, `group2` on second node and so on

then save code below as `docker-stack-arango.yml`

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  arangodb:
    image: "${ARANGO_IMAGE}"
    environment:
      ARANGO_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${ARANGO_ROOT_PASSWORD}"
      ARANGO_STORAGE_ENGINE: "${ARANGO_STORAGE_ENGINE}"
    volumes:
      - arangodb:/var/lib/arangodb3
      - arangodb_apps:/var/lib/arangodb3-apps
    ports:
      - target: 8529
        published: $ARANGO_PUBLISHED_PORT
        protocol: tcp
        mode: ingress
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      endpoint_mode: vip
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.labels.group==$INSTANCE_GROUP
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: $LIMITS_CPU
          memory: $LIMITS_MEMORY
      restart_policy:
        condition: any
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 60s
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        delay: 30s
    stop_grace_period: 60s

volumes:
  arangodb:
    external:
      name: ${ARANGO_VOLUME}
  arangodb_apps:
    external:
      name: ${ARANGO_APPS_VOLUME}
```

update and run config in shell/bash

```
export INSTANCE_GROUP="group1"
export INSTANCE_NAME="arango1"
export INSTANCE_PORT=8529
export INSTANCE_PASSWORD="do-not-use-this-password-in-production"

export ARANGO_IMAGE_TAG="3.4.0"
export ARANGO_IMAGE_REPO="arangodb/arangodb"
export ARANGO_IMAGE="${ARANGO_IMAGE_REPO}:${ARANGO_IMAGE_TAG}"
export ARANGO_VOLUME="arangodb-${INSTANCE_NAME}--3.4.0"
export ARANGO_APPS_VOLUME="arangodb-apps-${INSTANCE_NAME}--3.4.0"
export ARANGO_PUBLISHED_PORT=$INSTANCE_PORT
export ARANGO_STORAGE_ENGINE="rocksdb"
export ARANGO_ROOT_PASSWORD=$INSTANCE_PASSWORD
export LIMITS_CPU=1
export LIMITS_MEMORY=1024M
```

and then run deploy

```
docker stack deploy -c ./docker-stack-arango.yml $INSTANCE_NAME
```

to deploy second instance change `INSTANCE_NAME`, `INSTANCE_PORT` and `INSTANCE_GROUP` and run deploy again

then you can access instances via ip of any node with configured port

Comment: I appreciate the idea, but my experience with docker swarm has been less than positive.

Comment: no worries then, however, could you please share more about problem/s which you faced with docker swarm? reason is, that we're using it since it came out and ramping up platform on top of it, so if there's some dealbreaker which we didn't hit yet your insight could be lifesaving. thank you

Comment: We've been using it for our production systems, and we've been experiencing odd, unexpected behavior - networks randomly dropping out, containers "leaking" and slowly filling up the hard drive, dns not working, etc. Most of them could be fixed with a bit of attention, but it's annoying to have to maintain so much. The networking in general can also be a bit arcane, but maybe I'm just new to it also.

Comment: I agree, that there are some annoyances with setting everything up and it's not maintenance-free, but learning, continuous improvement, and maintenance is required by anything that you operate. What helped us to keep things simple, isolated and maintainable was dedicated swarm per tenant/project. Everything that needs communicate is on shared overlay network and exposed only through nginx proxy. All configs, secrets on swarm. All services either stateless or in failover, preferably cluster mode.

Answer (score 4):

No. Sharding is implemented solely for the purpose of distributing documents of any collection over multiple database servers. This is a means, to implement memory as well as load balancing on ArangoDB clusters.

Comment: That makes sense. Are there any strategies that you think would work for this situation?

Answer (score 4):

Arango can also be implemented using Kubernetes instead of Docker swarm (probably better).You could even create multiple server standalone instances if you really wanted to.  Whichever the implementation technology though, I guess what the other answers are trying to indicate is that if you have multiple independent databases, you could, have multiple instances of ArangoDB (or any other DB for that matter). The only time you would want keep multiple DBs in one instance is if the DBs are small enough that they will not compete for the server's resources.

Dividing you current instance should be fairly straight forward as you can backup, restore and manipulate the different DBs independently. Sharding and other associated concepts like partitioning are meant for times where you have to keep all the data within a single database. In that case, one needs to find a way to divide the data in multiple servers while keeping it as a single unit. That does not appear to be the case for here.

If you want to find out more on how to use ArangoDb with Kubernetes, you can find the documentation [here](https://docs.arangodb.com/devel/Manual/Deployment/Kubernetes/)